# Setting Ubuntu As The Default Operating System When Using The Windows Installer

Tags: wubi

How do you set Ubuntu as the default operating system after you have installed Ubuntu with the Windows Ubuntu Installer?

Answer (score 0):

I normally use a program called EasyBCD to change the boot entries. You can choose Ubuntu to be the default OS in that program. More info [here](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Changing+the+Default+Entry)

Comment: Why install a program to do something that is very easily available as a Windows setting? Unless you're adding custom boot entries (but that is not what was asked).